# Add Commas to a Sum LinQ

Tags: sql, linq, sum

I have a Group by Sum operation, but i would like to add ',' every 3 digits 
right now i get this output:

```
{ Pdv = REST, Total = $20786 }
```

But i would like this Output:

```
{ Pdv = REST, Total = $2,0786 }
```

This is my Linq Group By:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => new //here you count your total
                                            {
                                            Rid = x.Rid,
                                            Total = x.Total
                                            })
                                            .GroupBy(l => l.Rid) //and then grouping
                                            .Select(z => new
                                            {
                                            Turno = z.Key,

                                            Total = "$" + Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0)
                                            }))
                                        {
                                        //Loop Code
                                        }
```

Comment: You need to use formatting when you display it, Not when you do the Sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your "Total" must be String.

   ```
   String.Format("{#,##0.00}", 1243.50); // Outputs "1,243.50"

   String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", 1243.50); // Outputs "$1,243.50"

   String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", -1243.50); // Outputs"($1,243.50)" 

   String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", 0); // Outputs “Zero"
   ```